# Mysql query failed, but didn't clean up the disk space

Tags: mysql, join

I was trying to run the following statement with the hope to create a join of two existing tables.

```
create table CRS_PAIR
select concat_ws(',', a.TESTING_ID, b.TRAINING_ID, a.TESTING_C) as k, concat_ws(',', a.YTG, b.YTG) as YTG
from CRS_TESTING a, CRS_TRAINING b
where a.TESTING_C=b.TRAINING_C;
```

Currently the size of these two tables are:

```
mysql> SELECT table_name, round(((data_length + index_length) / (1024*1024)),2) as "size in megs" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "crs";
+----------------+---------------+
| table_name     | size in megs  |
+----------------+---------------+
| CRS_TESTING    |         36.59 |
| CRS_TRAINING   |        202.92 |
+----------------+---------------+
```

After a little over a day, The query finished and I got the following result.

```
140330  2:53:50 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table 'CRS_PAIR' is full
140330  2:53:54  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 9434006,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 9433498.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

It turned out that the size of `/var/lib/mysql` has grown to 246GB in disk space, and the disk run out of space. However, for some reason, the `CRS_PAIR` table does not show up in the shell. Even when I try to get the size of all databases.

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / (1024 * 1024) "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ; 
+--------------------+----------------------+
| Data Base Name     | Data Base Size in MB |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| crs                |            1426.4531 |
| information_schema |               0.0088 |
| mysql              |               0.6453 |
| performance_schema |               0.0000 |
+--------------------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.74 sec)
```

This is the show tables command.

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_crs  |
+----------------+
| CRS_TESTING    |
| CRS_TRAINING   |
 some other tables
+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`CRS_PAIR` is not there.

May I ask if anyone can help me figure out where this mysterious table went to so that I can clean up my disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `innodb_file_per_table` set (or set to 0) then InnoDB is going to put all your InnoDB tables into the pool file (usually `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`), expanding it as required to fit in written data. However, the engine never does any space reclamation. That means the ibdata1 file always grows, it never shrinks.

The only way to reduce the size of this file is to backup your data, shutdown MySQL, delete it, restart MySQL and then reload your data.

Comment: No I meant actually delete the file (`rm /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1' or wherever it is). MySQL will create a new one if it is absent when it starts.